# Unable to register "ChilkatMail_v7_9.dll" Version 7.9.2.0 with installer

Tags: c#, api, inno-setup, registration, chilkat

I am using  "ChilkatMail_v7_9.dll" Version 7.9.2.0 for creating EML file in C#.

Using Inno Setup Version 5.2.3.I am selecting Reg Type library option while creating installer.

Bit still unable to register this dll.

Is it because of virus?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Can you register the DLL outside the installer?  Does it return any errors or messages?

What exact flags did you put for the DLL in the [FILES] section?  From what I've seen, that version needs to have REGSERVER on the FLags.